# mod_rewrite pretty urls that may still have a querystring

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Thanks for taking the time to help!

The scenario is I have mod_rewrite making pretty looking URLs like `foobar.com/foo/bar/` into ugly ones like `foobar.com/bootstrap.php?url=foo/bar` and this works wonderfully.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/_]+)$ library/bootstrap.php?url=$1 [L]
```

In some cases (specifically Twitter's OAuth callback) the pretty URL will have a querystring appended to it like `foobar.com/foo/bar/?foo=bar&bar=foo`. I need the ugly output URL to look like `foobar.com/bootstrap.php?url=foo/bar&foo=bar&bar=foo`.

Please help as I have no idea what to do! I'll be looking of course as I'm sure some regular expression resource will reveal some clues.

If can come up with an answer please explain it too so I can understand for next time!

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/_]+)$ library/bootstrap.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: QSA for Query String Append - 
"This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule."

Comment: Whoop! Thanks! I was going to use `…?url=…%{QUUERY_STRING}` but your answer much cleaner and works beautifully!